# how can i fix this problem? I keep getting errors while using express and nodemon

Tags: nodemon

node:events:492
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::80
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1751:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1799:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1887:7)
at Function.listen (C:\Users\anish\OneDrive\Desktop\node javascript\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
at Object. (C:\Users\anish\OneDrive\Desktop\node javascript\express\app.js:21:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1778:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -4091,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 80
}

Node.js v18.17.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I tried running a file through nodemon app.js but it showed error.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running the app in two terminals `EADDRINUSE: address already in use` means the port is already in use. To be more specific, if you are running a node express app on 8000 and open a new terminal and try and run the same app **again** on the same port you will get the error.

Easiest fix, try restarting you PC. If that fails check if you are instantiating the app atleast twice

Answer (score 0):

Since the port is being used you can simply empty the port (kill the service running in that port) using:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti:3000)
```

This would kill port 3000. Replace it by your port in use (80 in your case).